# PHP Client-Side action to run a script server-side

Tags: php

I am sure this is possible and I have done this before but my mind has gone completely blank.

Basically I am trying to get the server to run a PHP script server side (using server side access tokens), based on an action from a client side user.

What's the best way to do this? Don't really need a detailed answer, just a push in the right direction!

Thanks.

(Windows Server)

Comment: Using Javascript and Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Use `AJAX`, for example with jQuery this way:

```
<script>
    $.ajax('something.php');
</script>
```